# ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.11 - Print causes Postback Issue in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, arcgis-js-api

I am new to ESRI and the javascript API. I am trying to implement the print task as seen here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Print.html

I am using the following code to create the Print functionality and it is appearing correctly as seen in the image:

```
require(["esri/widgets/Print"], function (Print) {
  var print = new Print({
    view: view,
    printServiceUrl: "https://printserviceurl/services/PrintService/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map"
  });

    // Adds widget below other elements in the top left corner of the view
    view.ui.add(print, {
      position: "bottom-left"
    });
});
```

[image]

The issue I am experiencing is clicking the "Advanced Options", "Export", or some other functionality causes a postback. This is an asp.net web application and the map is within an asp.net Master Page form control. This is causing the whole page to postback. Does anyone have a recommendation to prevent the full page postback and keep the print functionality? It does work correctly if I move it outside the  tag but to position it properly in the page the content area has to stay within the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue with the sketch widget.  It appears that the issue is that the buttons for all of the API's widgets are not created with the type="button" attribute, this causes the browser to assume its type="submit" and thus causes the Postback.  See here on [ESRI Forum](https://community.esri.com/thread/242539-printexport-widget-bug-button-clicking-causes-postback-in-aspnet).  To get around this for any of the ArcGIS API v 4.x widgets I have been adding the attribute after the widget renders:

```
var esriWidget = new Widget({
    view: this.view,
    container: 'widgetDiv',
});

$.each($('#widgetDiv').find("button"), function (i, btn) {
    $(btn).attr("type", "button");
});
```

This allows the widget to work as intended without causing a Postback.

Comment: That seems to solve most problems with widgets but there is still issues with the Sketch widget. The button to delete features gets regenerated every time a shape drawn shape is created or clicked. This causes it to lose the status. Any suggestions on what events to capture to draw it back? I tried the following to add the but when drawing multiple shapes the type="button" is lost.

sketch.on("update", function (event) {
            $.each($('#tempSketch').find("button"), function (i, btn) {
                $(btn).attr("type", "button");
            });
        });

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for this eventually. I used the following code to create the print functionality and inserted into a div outside of the asp.net form tag.

```
require(["esri/widgets/Print"], function (Print) {
            //create the print widget and insert into the print container
            var print = new Print({
                view: view,
                printServiceUrl: "https://printserviceurl/services/PrintService/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map"
            }, document.getElementById("divPrintContainer"));
        });
```

I then used styling to position the container where I want it. This step may require some custom styles depending where you want the div to appear. If it is outside the form tag it will prevent the whole page reloaded by the postback when interacting with the print widget.

```
<div id="divPrintContainer" style="position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:30px;"></div>
```